# UsedRange Propertie explanation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question concerning the use of UsedRange in my code.
The part that bothers me is:

```
lastcol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(UBound(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value, 2)).Column
```

I just want to get the last column in numeric form from this. It would have been enough to just use the UBound part but my predecessor chose to do it like that. I don't understand what the last part ".column" does. What does this ".column" do in the end?
Or in total why does the whole code work?

Comment: The `.Column` returns the column number property of a range object, which is what you want.  However, the way they are getting it is wholly unnecessary.  A simple equivalent would be: `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`

Comment: Note that relying on `UsedRange` to get the last row or column is notoriously unreliable however.  I would instead recommend performing a `Range.End` or a `Range.Find` to get the last row or column number.

Comment: @tigeravatar - Not *exactly* equivalent, given that `UBound(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value, 2)` is a runtime error if the `UsedRange` is less than 2 cells.  Also, the `UsedRange` doesn't have to begin in column A, so you can't just use the `Count`.  You need `.UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column` (assuming `With SomeSheet`).  Like you said, best avoided entirely.

Comment: The code works without any problems. It finds the last column with data in it. Since i know that we start at Column A i should have not problem with finding the right last column number.